# Entries iterator in Google's logadmin never returns iterator.Done

Tags: go, logging, gcloud

I'm using Google's logadmin package which comes in the logging package and trying to retrieve some logs by using a filter. Pretty simple... or so I thought. But the iterator never returns `iterator.Done`.

By looking at the opened issues in the package on GitHub and searching I couldn't find anything about it.

My code:

```
iter := client.Entries(ctx, logadmin.NewestFirst(),
    logadmin.Filter(
        fmt.Sprintf(`resource.type="cloud_function" resource.labels.function_name="%s"`, logger)))
var entries []string
for {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return nil
    default:
        entry, err := iter.Next()
        log.Print(fmt.Sprintf("[%s] [LEVEL]: %s\n [PAYLOAD]: %s\n [TIMESTAMP]: %s\n\n", logger,
            entry.Severity, entry.Payload, entry.Timestamp.String()))
        if err == iterator.Done {
            return nil
        }
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when it runs out of results?

Comment: @Adrian it just keeps stuck in the iter.Next() line

Comment: What do you mean "stuck"?

Comment: @Adrian it stops in that line as if waiting for more results and it does not log anything else or returns.

Comment: It looks like the `Next` function will implicitly wait for new log entries up until whatever is logging says it won't generate any more log entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to solve the problem by adding a timestamp to my filter as follows:

```
now := time.Now().Add(-24 * time.Hour).Format(time.RFC3339)
filter := fmt.Sprintf(`resource.type="cloud_function" resource.labels.function_name="%s" timestamp > %s`, logger, now)
```